# how to capture the document area of Photoshop

Tags: c#, node.js, electron, ui-automation

I'm working on a program and I need to capture the red area in the image below:

[image]

The problem is it should capture that part no matter what size the photoshop window is, so i can't hard code the coordinate.

I also tried inspect and FlaUInspect and they both get toggle between that area and full window area, also there are to automationId and the name is dynamic.

Since the ClassName is Photoshop I have tried the c# code below with flaui and doesn't work:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using FlaUI.UIA3;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] AllProcesslist = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process Proc in AllProcesslist)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Proc.MainWindowTitle) && Proc.MainModule.FileName == @"D:\photoshop\Adobe Photoshop CC 2015\Photoshop.exe")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Window Found!");
                    var app = new FlaUI.Core.Application(Proc);
                    using (var automation = new UIA3Automation())
                    {
                        var window = app.GetMainWindow(automation);
                        Bitmap image = window.FindFirstDescendant(cf => cf.ByClassName("Photoshop")).Capture();
                        image.Save("sample.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

My program is with electron but if you know how to do that in any programming languages i can easily implement that in my electron program.

Comment: Please can you elaborate on how your question is related to C#? If it isn't, you should remove the tag.

Comment: @John I have edited the question, this is the code i tried to do that with UI automation, is it possible to capture that part with UI automation in c#?

Comment: Do you just want a screenshot of what's on the screen or do you want the actual rendered control from the running Photoshop window?

Comment: How is this related to Node or Electron? Please don't use unrelated tags. UI Automation is already used by accessibility tools, including Windows' own tools. There are tools available that can inspect applications and show you the window structure and what accessibility tools will see

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  I can easily run the c# code with EdgeJs in my electron program..., and i'm mostly familiar with c# so i don't know how to work with c++ node addon

Comment: @hamidreza so your question's text has nothing to do with your question?? Or is the actual question you should be asking be how to call UI Automation from Node, making any reference to FlaUI irrelevant? UI Automation is a system API, specifically COM, not a .NET feature.

Comment: And since UI Automation uses COM you should be looking for libraries for COM interop, like [cominterop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cominterop)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to capture that part and show it in my electron program, i know i can do that in c# but i'm not sure with nodejs modules, so maybe you also know how to do that in nodejs...

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will take a look at `cominterop` and let you know if it works.

Comment: @John I only need a screenshot of the document area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no ui automation frameworks for photoshop, flaui and inspect.exe don't work with photoshop, so i used the capture method to get a screenshot of photoshop window and then crop it.

this is the final code:

```
using FlaUI.UIA3;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Control
{
    class Photoshop
    {
        public static int processId;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out int processId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool GetWindowPlacement(IntPtr hWnd, ref WINDOWPLACEMENT lpwndpl);

        private struct WINDOWPLACEMENT
        {
            public int length;
            public int flags;
            public int showCmd;
            public Point ptMinPosition;
            public Point ptMaxPosition;
            public Rectangle rcNormalPosition;
        }

        // take a screenshot of the  document
        public async Task<object> screen(int handle)
        {
            Bitmap final = null;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId((IntPtr)handle, out processId);
            Process Proc = Process.GetProcessById(processId);

            WINDOWPLACEMENT placement = new WINDOWPLACEMENT();
            GetWindowPlacement((IntPtr)Proc.MainWindowHandle, ref placement);
            var app = new FlaUI.Core.Application(Proc);
            var automation = new UIA3Automation();
            Bitmap capture = app.GetMainWindow(automation).Capture();

            if (placement.showCmd == 1) // 1- normal, 3- maximize
            {
                final = documentArea(capture);
            }
            else
            {
                Bitmap crop = cropImage(capture, new Rectangle(8, 8, capture.Width - 16, capture.Height - 16));
                final = documentArea(crop);
            }
              
            return ImgtoBase64(final);
        }

        public static Bitmap documentArea(Bitmap b)
        {
            int x = 45;
            int y = 87;
            Rectangle area = new Rectangle(x, y, b.Width - x, b.Height - y);
            return cropImage(b, area);
        }

        public static Bitmap cropImage(Bitmap b, Rectangle r)
        {
            Bitmap nb = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(nb))
            {
                g.DrawImage(b, -r.X, -r.Y);
                return nb;
            }
        }

        public static string ImgtoBase64(Bitmap img)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
            byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
            return Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
        }
    }
}
```